# Automatic application installer with pre-set options

Tags: windows, automation, installer

We have to re-install this specific software with different settings every time.

Would it be possible to make a script or something(any idea is a good idea) to be able to pre-set the options/attributes you would want the installer to have enabled and do the installation process for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Find out if the program offers an MSI, which will make this way easier.

I would try to open the MSI with a tool like ORCA, Microsoft's MSI editor.

If the MSI has no documented unattended install feature, you can use ORCA to find out if it supports unattended installs and the command line options you need to use to make it successful.

For the faint at heart, I don't recommend altering the MSI . But it is possible to alter MSIs to make even the most difficult installs unattended.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, most applications install by running an MSI (Microsoft Installer) compatible app/file.

MSI's contain a great deal of often complex installation logic, settings, configuration mechanisms, etc. While you can unpick an MSI, modify it and repackage it to your liking, this can result in badly broken app configurations.

Different apps configure themselves in different ways - some use the registry, some use XML config files, others use config files with their own format. Some use multiple config points - registry, files, etc.

If you really want to configure this app, I recommend trying to work out where it keeps all its config data. Then you can write the necessary script to allow you to modify the registry and/or modify the app's config file(s) with the settings you want.

Understand, however, that unless you're careful, there's a good chance you could confuse the app - often in subtle, hard-to-track-down ways and you may end up corrupting data (particularly if the app stores data in files and/or databases)!

Tread carefully!